# html5 local storage split JSON.stringify data

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I have stored some data in a value called Test as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/DrFS6/) and below.

```
    var test = "yellow,green";
    var storedTest = localStorage.setItem("Test", JSON.stringify(test));
    $('body').append('color:' + localStorage.getItem('Test'));
```

Currently my html output is

```
    color:"yellow,green"
```

But I want to be able to split my variable so it outputs.

```
    color:"yellow", color:"green"
```

What do I need to do to acheive this?

Comment: `String.split(',')` is what you are looking for.

Comment: you could just change the way you save it..make it an array of objects. `[{color: 'yellow'},{color: 'green'}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can do this:

```
$('body').append('color:' +
                 localStorage.getItem('Test').replace(/,/g,'", color: "') + '"')
```

That is, replace each comma with the text `", color: "` (where the double-quotes are part of the replace string), as well as putting `'color:'` at the beginning and a double-quote at the end.

If you want to get the individual colours into an array so that you can process them in some other way you can do this:

```
var colorArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Test')).split(',');
// gives ["yellow", "green"]
```

Demo (of both): http://jsfiddle.net/TUFfS/

Comment: Regex for JavaScript is explained [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) (see also the [`.replace()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)). A more general explanation is at http://www.regular-expressions.info/